# Associated product not getting added to parent product. Configurable product issue

Tags: configurable-product

I have a strange situation. 
We have a configurable product with 2 dropdown options. Colour and Size. 
After creating the product and saving it. we go to the associated products tab.

When we add products via the Quick Add feature. We do get all the signs of a functioning system. Although the product seems to be added under the options, in the table beneath there is no action. after saving the product all is gone. The simple products are created perfectly. No errors in exception, system or apache logs.

I added a photo.

[image: Items not added.]

EDIT
Good to mention. that the site is full of configurable products (shoes) those have just 1 configurable item (size) those work without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a filter in the simple products grid. I see that the first column (the one with the checkbox in the header) has the `Nee` selected as filter. I assume `Nee` means `No`. Change that to `All` or `Yes` and hit `Search`.

Comment: Sorry about that. yes but that was for trying to search them even without filter and the dropdown to all no results... - Just edited the screenshot thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the "Apply To" field of your configurable attribute has "simple product" option selected along with the "Configurable Product".